# Should this have been deleted?

Tags: discussion

This answer was deleted and converted to a comment

Should this have been deleted?

> The 48 is all in. There must have been a side pot.

[Why did I win a portion of this hand?](https://poker.stackexchange.com/questions/6999/why-did-i-win-a-portion-of-pot-in-this-hand)

The stated standard is:

Answers that do not fundamentally answer the question may be removed. This includes answers that are:

- commentary on the question or other answers
- asking another, different question
- “thanks!” or “me too!” responses
- exact duplicates of other answers
- barely more than a link to an external site
- not even a partial answer to the actual question

It fundamentally answers the question and is none of the items on that list.

Answer (score 1):

I see your point. However, I also see why it was moved to comments, rather than just deleting it.

The answer is likely correct. I think Radu (Mod) saw it at just that and not an explanation too. If an answer is just going to be a "partial" answer in comparison to another more detailed answer & explanation (for example the one [here](https://poker.stackexchange.com/a/7001/88)), then you may as well have either edited someone else's answer to be more detailed, or not answered at all, and/or voted on other more detailed answers.

Thus it was more like "commentary on the question or other answers". Similar to saying "me too!", "I agree". In those cases, a simple vote is usually better.

I hope that makes sense.

Comment: Check the time line.  My answer was there first - by 10 hours.  There was no answer when I posted.

Comment: Yes, I see that now. It's likely the correct answer. The answer was actually auto-flagged by the system as "low quality". This usually happens with answers that are very short. Those type of answers are discouraged, by the system and users in general. I can see why Radu moved it still, although it may have been better to wait a while before acting. As it stands, I'd prefer to leave it as a comment, unless of course you want to give a more details that adds to the completeness of your response.